# SyntaxError related to line.rfind

Tags: python

In the past I was using line.rfind to find a fixed variable and my script worked fine. However, now that I am trying to use line.rfind to find a changing variable, I am getting a syntax error for a line of code that used to work. Here is the code I have.

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date = datetime.now()
date1 = date + timedelta(days=1)

class city :
    def __init__(self, city_name, link, latitude, longitude) :
            self.name = city_name
            self.url = link
            self.low0 = 0
            self.high1 = 0
            self.high2 = 0
            self.low1 = 0
            self.low2 = 0
            self.lat = latitude
            self.long = longitude

    def retrieveTemps(self) :
            filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

            # get lines from result into array
            lines = filehandle.readlines()

            # (for each) loop through each line in lines
            line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
            for line in lines:
                    line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter

                    # find string, position otherwise position is -1

                    position0 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date1.strftime("%A"))

                    # string is found in line
                    if position0 > 0 :
                         self.low0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
```

The error I am getting says...

```
if position0 > 0 :
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on what is wrong? I assume it is somehow related to the change I made in this line...

```
position0 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date1.strftime("%A"))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As pointed out byt @artsiom-rudzenka it's a missing parantheses. I recommend you use smart editor (or IDE) that'll point out such simple mistakes for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to use closing bracet ')'. Change to:

```
position0 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date1.strftime("%A")))
```

Comment: I swore I counted them multiple times! So simple. Thanks.

Comment: I will as soon as it allows me!